# iPhone 4/4s Spotlight Search Problem

Tags: iphone, spotlight

Spotlight Search on iPhone 4s doesn't show any results.

Everything is checked under Settings -> General -> Spotlight Search.

Restart doesn't help. New contacts don't appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found in a comment by "yigitcanakkas" here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfBSrZ1p2Tw

Whenever my search becomes unresponsive, my mail becomes unresponsive too. I open the mail and it's plain white, nothing happens, 5 seconds later it crashes, I open it again and it works this time. After that search becomes active again.

Comment: Not happened again for months now. Probably they fixed it in one of the updates.

Answer (score 2):

Under Settings -> General -> Spotlight Search

are the areas you want to search selected (tick on the left hand side), if not just tap the group (Contacts, Applications, etc) to add them to Spotlight Search.

Comment: Thanks for the help, everything is already checked under Settings -> General -> Spotlight Search. It seems it's a bug in searching mail.

Comment: what are you expecting to happen? All senders in email to appear as contacts?

Comment: Nope, there is an issue with spotlight search. For some reason sometimes it just stops working.

Answer (score -1):

I went in settings/spotlight settings then unchecked everything except for spotlight suggestions, works great now. I don't usually need to search anything on my phone just net